# Server settings in modern JavaScript apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm looking for a solution to have server settings in a config file of some sort separate from the JS app (which I could be running in dev or prod (built) mode) but allow for the server to replace the file with a new one at random point in time (when settings have changed) and allow the JS app to pick it up and refresh it's settings.

This is mainly for setting URLs to API endpoints.

My choice of JS framework is Angular 1 and 4 but answers geared generally towards various JS frameworks/libraries are applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to have server settings in a config file of some sort separate from the JS app

If you are thinking about having your server settings exposed to the front you are gonna have a bad time ;)

I will assume that you think you will keep API URLs and maybe some config along with it in a separate file while you develop. Then I can advise two approaches:

1.) SIMPLE - Have a single JS file with a single object with all the necessary API URLs and settings in a tree like structure for organisational purposes. So you have a dev, a test and production property with everything in them. Once you load app 1st thing that should the app do is load the correct settings. This is fast and doesn't require any additional knowledge. Everywhere you had something configurable hard coded you replace it with a variable that derives from that file. This should suffice for simple applications.

2.) POWERFULL - For bigger applications with loads of different dependencies and more formal and professional approach do what most people do, use NodeJs, leverage Grunt or Gulp to help you version dependencies and write scripts for different builds. It requires you to install and learn to use new stuff but offers you way more power.

Even better combine this two approaches, link the external dependencies dynamically with the build and internal via including the correct JS file with all the API information.

You can also use other npm modules to assist you with your development like precompiling CSS, lint your code, rearrange and organise files by types into folders, auto-name files or folders.

Basically, MOST of the REPETITIVE tasks you do while developing can be automated this way. This truly shines on bigger projects when all this is handled by someone who is proficient and experienced with the 2nd approach, it can save months of repetitive tasks across the team.

Comment: My question was mostly about what you talk in point 1. I'm thinking of a commonjs module that's separate from the build and server-generated. Also, please note, this is not about server settings but client settings to the server (API URLs).

Comment: Then go with number suggestion 1. Why do you need it to be server generated? That implies you need to contact the server to obtain it.  So you already know the API you wanna use. Or is it some wierd way to provide dynamic loading, like you have 1 server who acts like load balancer and gives your app different server if some are overburdened. Because that kind of things should be done on backend dynamically. Does the API have many variations to use or only a couple of them? If couple, make static config files then include them in your app and link the correct one in when bootstrapping.

Comment: The key is this file would be separate from the clientside app build process. Server generated or manually created doesn't really matter.

Comment: We're already using gulp for other tasks. This is not a gulp matter.

Comment: So have a single or multiple (1 per environment) .js files and require correct one during bootstrapping and all config should be there once app starts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gulp (or even npm) as a task runner to do this kind of work. Maybe this article would help? https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

The main point of a task runner is that you can set a specific variable ie prod or development, and the task runner can then switch out your config files with the present definitions for prod or dev config.